# Taking last column of a 3D array

Tags: python-3.x

I Have a 3D array composed by 4 columns. I want to extract only the last column (from 0.626 to 0.022) in order to plot it.

```py
yhat = estimator.predict(Xtest, verbose=0)
array([[[ 0.02373935, -0.00453718,  0.01974867,  0.62695163]],

       [[ 0.02106621, -0.00397644,  0.01761295,  0.62469435]],

       [[ 0.02013615, -0.00363547,  0.01690874,  0.62409896]],

       ...,

       [[-0.00133965, -0.0020067 ,  0.00370775,  0.02289007]],

       [[-0.00133965, -0.0020067 ,  0.00370775,  0.02289007]],

       [[-0.00133965, -0.0020067 ,  0.00370775,  0.02289007]]],
      dtype=float32)
```

> "shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
>
> **ValueError**: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (912,) and (912, 1, 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy multidimensional array slicing:

```
last_column = arr[:, :, -1]
```

Comment: I'm getting some strange things happen: if i print last_column in the editor i get the right sequence:
```python
array([[ 6.2695163e-01],
       [ 6.1686254e-01],
       ...
       [ 2.2890069e-02],
       [ 2.2890069e-02]], dtype=float32)
```
But if I print from terminal I get multiple rows:

```Python
 ...
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]]
```
Infact in the plot i get multiple curves.

Comment: @Nikos90 The actual values are the same, `1000000` is the same as `1e6`. That's scientific notation, it means `6.2695163 * 10^(-1)`.

Comment: @MrGreek I'm an Automation engenieer, I know very well notations :D. 
Maybe if you look my second answer you get the problem better.

Comment: @Nikos90 I think that's just a display difference, the values are still the same, perhaps the terminal displays things differently than the editor, but they're storing the same values.

Comment: Here is the thing: `last_cloumn` stores **multiple predicted curves**, but I need only one curve. This curve is a prediction from an LSTM nn with a TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features))) output layer ( this is why I have a 3D array from yhat) for a multistep output prediction. I don't understand why i'm getting these multiple curves.

Comment: @Nikos90 Try taking only `last_column[0]`, in case you have multiples of it.

Answer (score 0):

From

```py
last_column = yhat[:, :, -1]
```

I'm getting some strange things happen: if i print last_column in the editor i get the right sequence:

```py
array([[ 6.2695163e-01],
       [ 6.1686254e-01],
       ...
       [ 2.2890069e-02],
       [ 2.2890069e-02]], dtype=float32)
```

But if I print from terminal I get multiple rows:

```
 ...
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]
 [0.57803965 0.5793313  0.5800704  ... 0.28363833 0.28206974 0.2802861 ]]
```

Infact in the plot i get multiple curves.